# Two switches, and using the others IP addresses while connected to the other

Tags: switch, router

I have Two switches on the same rack:

- *Switch A* uses `192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.254` range IP addresses
- *Switch B* uses `100.1.0.1 - 100.1.0.254` range IP addresses

What I want is for me to assign a *Switch A* IP address to a *Switch B* connected PC, which will be able to ping *Switch A* connected networks.

Would that be possible?

I am not at all fluent in networking, so I don't understand most of the articles I have read that might be the solution to my problem, so please bear with me.

Comment: Please, a diagram or an explanation of how they're connected can be very useful to have a better understanding of your environment. Also, let us know if they are L2 or L3 switches, VLANs, etc.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: Check if the switch supports layer 3 switching. If it does u should find some resources on VLAN ..... It is very possible what u wish to achieve......good luck !

Answer (score 1):

Your question really needs more detail, and it is not completely clear, but I think you need to use VLANs.

VLANs logically separate multiple networks on the same switch. Some switch interfaces can be in one VLAN, some in another, and others in other VLANs. For hosts connected to one VLAN to communicate with hosts in any other VLAN requires a router.

For example, assume the two switches each have 24 ports, and VLAN 10 has the `192.168.0.0/24` network, while VLAN 20 has the `100.1.0.0/24` network. You could assign the first 12 ports on each switch to VLAN 10, and the last 12 ports on each switch to VLAN 20. You will need to connect the two switch with a trunk, and you will need a trunk from one of the switches to a router if you want the devices on VLAN 10 to be able to communicate with the devices on VLAN 20.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.  It's quite basic really.  The subnets are typically bound to a designated VLAN, each of which has a default gateway to enable inter-vlan routing/connectivity.

First, create an identical numbered/named VLAN for each subnet on both switches, maybe call them VLAN192 and VLAN100.  Enable a link (an uplink) between the switches to carry traffic for both VLAN's.  This is called a trunk interface.

Now that each switch has access to both VLAN's, enable IP routing on one of them and configure an interface VLAN192 and an interface VLAN100 with an IP address on each subnet, in other words interface VLAN192 gets 192.168.0.254 255.255.255.0, for example.  Same for other VLAN.

Now, clients with IP addressing including a default gateway will be able to communicate cross VLAN.

If your switches don't support routing (layer3), you will require a dedicated router for interVLAN connectivity.